# How to merge pandas calculated series into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am doing some calculation in pandas, my Pandas dataframe named data is followings:

Userid ------ hashtagcount

1034   ----        3
 1034   ----        0
 1034   ----        5
 1337   ----        2
 1337   ----        1
 1337   ----        2
 2288   ----        6
....   ----         .

I have other feature columns also. and i used following to select the rows having repeated values in my pandas dataset. for eg, UserId occur 3 times above.

unique_spam_row=data[["UserID","UserCreatedAt","UserDescriptionLength","UserFollowersCount","UserFriendsCount","UserLocation"]]

i remove the duplicate values.
spam_data=unique_spam_row.drop_duplicates()

but 
i need to save average hashtag count of each UserID in new  spam_data dataframe.

so i did

spam=data.groupby('UserID')["HashtagCount"].sum()

i got

UserID
1034    -       8
1337    -       5
2288    -       9
................

type(spam) gives me , it is a series, i need to add these 8, 5 , 9 ....as a AvgHashtag columns in spam_data dataframe where repeted rows were already removed ...
 Many thanks for suggessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) should work:

```
data['count'] = data.groupby('UserID')["HashtagCount"].transform('sum')
```

This will return a series with it's index aligned to your original df so you can add it as a column correctly

Comment: It worked indeed. but i have to do data.loc[:,'count']  for assigning slice from dataframe.

Comment: how to get rid of it.
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 40798 elements, new values have 40841 elements